# laravel returns null value using ajax onclick event

Tags: ajax, mysqli, laravel-5

I have this function inside controller my problem is that the onclick event works fine but the issue is that it does not select an item id but it instead returns a blank textfield.

public function inboxData(Request $request)
    {

```
    $address = Inbox::select(['id', 'text', 'status', 'sender_address', 'created_at'])
        ->where('account_no', Furahia::getAccount()->first()->account_no)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $dataTables = Datatables::of($address)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($address) {
        return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onclick="fun_edit($address->id)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Reply</a>';
        });
    if ($keyword = $request->get('search')['value']) {
        $dataTables->filterColumn('rownum', 'whereRaw', '@rownum  + 1 like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
    }
    return $dataTables->make(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted to fill in the value of `$address->id` instead of the text

```
public function inboxData(Request $request) {
    $address = Inbox::select(['id', 'text', 'status', 'sender_address', 'created_at'])
        ->where('account_no', Furahia::getAccount()->first()->account_no)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $dataTables = Datatables::of($address)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($address) {
            return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onclick="fun_edit(' . $address->id . ')" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Reply</a>';
    });

    if ($keyword = $request->get('search')['value']) {
        $dataTables->filterColumn('rownum', 'whereRaw', '@rownum  + 1 like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
    }
     return $dataTables->make(true);
}
```